# Microformats for a product page in magento

Tags: magento, microformats, rich-snippets

I have a product page in a Magento store and I'm trying to implement Rich snippets with Microformats in this page.

I followed this guide : http://yoast.com/rich-snippets-magento/, but when I try the Rich Snippets Testing Tool on this page : http://wfltp.zone1global.com/bulb/3m/new_compactview_sx30_basic.html
I get

> "The following errors were found during preview generation: Empty
>   page. This page does not contain authorship or rich snippet markup."

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first guess, you are not modifying the right template files. Have you tried viewing the source of your pages to see if the tags are actually in there?

If your tags are in there, you are not doing something right. Use the Google Rich Snippets Testing Tool for your testing (after all it is primarily Google that is going to be using these snippets). http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets

Comment: As an example this page utilizes rich snippets for the product page in Magento http://workingperson.com/workwear-1/shirts/carhartt-shirts/carhartt-shirts-pocket-t-shirt-k87blk-88443.html

Comment: I'm editing the right template files. I gave a link to my product page where you can see the Microformats I've added. As I said, I've added the Microformats to the page and used the Rich Snippets Testing Tool but I get the message I wrote in my question without any information on what is the problem.

Comment: Your link requires a username and password to view. I think that is your problem. Take off the htpasswd requirement and Google will be able to view your site.